# error while passing the value in python

Tags: python

```
 def row_minimum(x,L):
  L=L
  if x=='1':
    row_minimum1=min(L[0],L[1],L[2],L[3],L[4])
    return row_minimum1
  elif x=='2':
    row_minimum2=min(L[5],L[6],L[7],L[8],L[9])
    return row_minimum2
  elif x=='3':
    row_minimum3=min(L[10],L[11],L[12],L[13],L[14])
    return row_minimum3
  table(L)


 def user_input(y):
    def user_input(y):
        if y in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
            condition = False
        elif y !=['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
            condition = True
            while condition == True:
                z=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
                if z in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
                    condition = False
            return z

def  menu(a,L):
  if a==1:
    display_table(L)
  elif a==2:
    x=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
    user_input(x)
    print (user_input)
    if user_input(x) in ['1','2','3']:
        mini = row_minimum(x,l)
        print ("2")
        print("Minimum is:",row_minimum(x,L))
```

this is the programm to check the user input but whenever i pass the input it goes through the function but it gives a built in function function user_input at 0x021DCB28> for user_input(y)

Comment: Your `elif` clause tests `condition`, but you haven't set it in that case.

Comment: yes even though it gives me a same  <function user_input at 0x0250DB28>

Comment: @user2939612: Show us how you're invoking this function.

Comment: That is not an error. It is caused by `print(user_input)`. `user_input` is a function, which is what is being printed. If you are trying to print the result of calling `user_input` on `x`, then try `print(user_input(x))`

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
def user_input(y):
    if y in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
        condition = False
    else:
        condition = True
        while condition == True:
            z=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
            if z in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
                condition = False
        return z


print user_input('1')
print user_input('4')
```

**Edit**

If you get something like `<function user_input at 0x0000000002CB1128>`, its because you are printing the function. (And it's not an error)

```
print user_input # This is not wath you want
```

This instead is what you want:

```
print user_input(...) # Where ... is the parameter you are giving to your function
```

Comment: it still give me the same error,<function user_input at 0x0250DB28>

Comment: I'm sure you are printing something like `user_input`, try printing: `print user_input('1')`, you were missing the parameter `y`

Comment: yes that was right but it still does not give me the value i am looking for.

Comment: OP is using python3. Your code apperars to be python2, which will result in syntax errors

Comment: @user2939612 If you get a result that is not the expected one, then make another post specifying the problem you have.

Comment: i want the number in parenthesis to sync with no from the user instead of hard coding, i did correct that part,  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two nested definitions of `user_input`, so when you call it you get out the function definition instead of what it is supposed to return. Delete one of the `def user_input(y):` lines and fix your indentation and I bet it works.