# error while passing the value in python when user enter the value

Tags: python

```
def row_minimum(x,L):
  L=L
  if x=='1':
    row_minimum1=min(L[0],L[1],L[2],L[3],L[4])
    return row_minimum1
  elif x=='2':
    row_minimum2=min(L[5],L[6],L[7],L[8],L[9])
    return row_minimum2
  elif x=='3':
    row_minimum3=min(L[10],L[11],L[12],L[13],L[14])
    return row_minimum3
  table(L)



    def user_input(y):
        if y in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
            condition = False
        elif y !=['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
            condition = True
            while condition == True:
                z=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
                if z in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
                    condition = False
            return z

def  menu(a,L):
  if a==1:
    display_table(L)
  elif a==2:
    x=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
    user_input(x)
    print (user_input(x))
    if user_input(x) in ['1','2','3']:
        mini = row_minimum(x,l)
        print ("2")
        print("Minimum is:",row_minimum(x,L))
```

i am getting the value of user_input(x) to none instead i want it to take the value from the user and compare in the if statement and do the minimum.

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698225/error-while-passing-the-value-in-python) again?

Comment: Your `user_input()` function only returns a value some of the time. for example `user_input('1')` will not return a value. Thus if `x = user_input('1')` then the value of `x` is `None`

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested definition for `user_input` and the first one doesn't return anything, resulting in `None` being returned. Take out the first or second `def`.

Note that this is far from the only thing wrong with this program.

Comment: i change the definition but it still has a none value

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_input()` function seems like a bad idea. As far as I can tell it is meant to check for bad input, and keeps asking for input until it gets good input. The problem is, it only returns if the initial input was bad, if the initial input was good, then the function does not return.

You can just get rid of this function altogether, since you end up checking the input anyway. you can just do:

```
def  menu(a,L):
    if a==1:
        display_table(L)
    elif a==2:
        while True:
            x=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
            print x
            if x in ['1','2','3']:
                mini = row_minimum(x,l)
                print ("2")
                print("Minimum is:",row_minimum(x,L))
                break
            elif x in ['A','B','C','D','E']:
                whatever you want to do here
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a logic issue in user_input() function. If I understood it right, you are trying to check if y is one of the row/column names and set condition to False in this case. Otherwise (if it is not in your list of allowed characters), you want to set the condition to True and re-prompt the user for correct input until she gives you the value you want.
If it is so, you better be checking y if it is NOT in the list. Your code, though, checks if y is not the LIST itself: y !=['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']. Even if the user gives you a good value, say 'B' it is still not equal to the list of strings ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E'], it is IN this list (that`s what you should be checking for). I think, it`ll help if you rewrite the function to make it something like:

```
def user_input(y):
    if y in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
        condition = False
    else:
        condition = True
        while condition == True:
            z=input("Enter a row (as a number) or a column (as and uppercase letter):")
            if z in ['1','2','3','A','B','C','D','E']:
                condition = False
        return z
```

You may also want to experiment with Python style guide and make this code look nicer ;)